# spring security:intercept-url pattern access="#id == 1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i have project were iam spring security 3.1.3  and mvc 3.2

i want too allow a url wehen in the userid in the path is matching the principal userid

```
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/{id}/edit" access="#id == principal.userId"/>
```

http use-expressions it set to true and when a try principal.userId == 1 it works but i need to use the extracted value from the url.

i already tried all possible combinations.

Comment: want i found was this but it didn't work 

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?130413-Web-Security-Expressions-and-PathVariables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible. But there is another way. You can define you own web expression that will be responsible for extracting of id parameter from URL. It may looks like that:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/user/{id}/edit" access="getIdUrlPathParameter() == principal.userId"/>
```

To do so you need:

 1. Add CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot that extends **WebSecurityExpressionRoot**

 2. Add getIdUrlPathParameter() method. It will have access to HttpServletRequest object.

 3. Define CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler that extends **DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler**. Override createSecurityExpressionRoot method abd use your CustomWebSecurityExpressionRoot here.

 4. Define custom access decision manager (xml below)

 5. Inject it into your **http** element via  access-decision-manager-ref attribute

```
<security:http access-decision-manager-ref="customAccessDecisionManagerBean" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/{id}/edit" access="getIdUrlPathParameter() == principal.userId"/>
</security:http>
<bean id="customWebSecurityExpressionHandler" class="com.domain.security.CustomWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
<bean id="customAccessDecisionManagerBean" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
                <property name="expressionHandler" ref="customWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [cannot be done](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?130413-Web-Security-Expressions-and-PathVariables&p=425360#post425360) with Spring Security.