# Spring Security - showing content specific to the logged in user

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, jsp-tags

Say I have a profile page, which has an 'edit your profile' link. The profile page can be viewed by all the users, but the edit link button should be visible only for a logged in user viewing his profile, not another user's profile.

As of now I have this code,

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
<sec:authentication property="principal.username" var="principal"/>
<c:if test="${profile_username eq principal}">   <!--profile_username is the username of the viewed profile  -->
<!-- edit your profile link -->
</c:if>
</sec:authorize>
```

Is there a cleaner way a doing this?? May be a one liner like

`<sec:authorize access="isTheSamePerson()"/>`.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You shouldn't need the sec:authorize tag, if the user isn't logged in, the principal object will be null, and the c:if test will fail.  Not exactly what you wanted, but it would clean it up a little.

Comment: nice catch. But, that won't work without an sec:auth tag. It will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take into account actual domain object. There is special [ACL](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#domain-acls) feature in Spring Security for these purposes. You can set up it and use corresponding [accesscontrollist](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6991) tag:

```
<sec:accesscontrollist hasPermission="2" domainObject="${profile}">
    <!-- Your edit link goes here -->
    <!-- "2" means write permission -->
    <!-- Be sure that you use Spring Security >= 3.1.2. This syntax may not works for smaller versions due to bugs  -->
</sec:accesscontrollist>
```

It may be an overkill if you have only one situation like this.

Option number 2. You can define a custom web security expression:

```
<sec:authorize access="isOwner(#profile)"/>.
```

It is not [so simple too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185070/spring-securityintercept-url-pattern-access-id-1/14199105#14199105).

I think a custom JSP tag ([tag file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296235/jsp-tricks-to-make-templating-easier)) will be the most simple solution:

```
<customtags:authorizeeditaccount account="${profile}"/>
```

This tag will do the same things. It will look much better.

Comment: Good solutions If I have too many cases. Otherwise would be an overkill.