# Spring security intercept-url pass pattern parameter to access method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, parameter-passing

In spring security, we can limit access to certaiin web resources using this construct:
`<intercept-url pattern="/admin.xhtml" access="hasPermission('admin')" />`

Now, I have a lot of pages, to access each, one should have special permission with same name as the page name. `intercept-url` accepts pattern but doesn't seem to provide parameter passing from regex matched groups in `pattern` to `access`. I want something like this:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/([a-z]+).xhtml" access="hasPermission('$1')" />
```

Comment: A lot = how many? 10? 100? 1000? You can write some script in some other language to generate a list if it is around 100. But if it is 1000, the design is quite questionable.

Comment: I believe this is a very common requirement to grant access to certain URLs dynamically, regardless of how many pages in the application. Even 10 line of copy-paste code is normally error-prone.

Comment: Access role is introduced to group together (many - thousands or more) users under several access roles for the purpose of reducing the need to maintain very large access role table per user. I'm not sure why there would be too many roles to do it by hand.

Comment: My requirement is actually `hasPermission()`, will fix the question.

Comment: I'm think you must use SpringSecurity's ACL for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use matched regex groups in your access rule.
As a workaround you can try to define a custom web security expression. It will be responsible for extracting of some matched regex group:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/([a-z]+).xhtml" access="hasPermission(extractGroup('$1', '/([a-z]+).xhtml'))" />
```

During execution **extractGroup(...)** method will be able to use current HttpRequest.  This solution will have two disadvatages:1)  it's not so simple to do 2) regex pattern will be duplicated in your conf. If it's OK for you then you can read how to add a custom web security expression [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185070/spring-securityintercept-url-pattern-access-id-1/14199105#14199105).