# Is there a way to configure Roles in a property file for Spring security MVC app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring security MVC application. In few JSP files I have code that looks like this:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_FOO', 'ROLE_BAR')">
  <!--do something here-->  
</sec:authorize>
```

I have to make code changes (changing `ROLE_FOO` to something else) when deploying the app to production because it has different role names. So I was wondering whether there is a way to configure these role names in a property file and then pick those inside the `<sec:authorize>` tag.

So the code would look something like this:

Property File:

```
Admin_Roles = ROLE_FOO ROLE_BAR
```

and JSP

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole(<get roles from Admin_Roles in prop file>)">
  <!--do something here-->  
</sec:authorize>
```

btw, I am using Active Directory for authentication so these roles are pre-configured in the active directory for test and production.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is the easiest way. But you can write your own expression.

This link should be very useful. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185070/spring-securityintercept-url-pattern-access-id-1/14199105#14199105)

Since there are some differences between each version. You had better take a look at the source code of `DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler` to make sure you do not miss anything when override `createSecurityExpressionRoot`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you would do this for a variable number of roles, but for a fixed number have you tried something like this?

JSP:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('${adminRole1}', '${adminRole2}')">
  <!--do something here-->  
</sec:authorize>
```

Controller:

```
@Value("#{myprops.admin_role_1}"}
private String adminRole1;
@Value("#{myprops.admin_role_2}"}
private String adminRole2;
...
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public String hello(final Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("adminRole1", adminRole1);
  model.addAttribute("adminRole2", adminRole2);
  ...
}
```

and config XML:

```
<bean id="myprops"
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <!-- External property files -->
      <value>file:${somepathvar}/adminroles.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: This might work as I only have a fixed number of roles. However, I am using the roles as part for `<intercept url>` in my app-servlet.xml as well. How would I access the roles via properties there?

Comment: Via custom web security expression for example, see @Willy answer