# Spring Security Ant Matchers Runtime

Tags: spring-security

I have database like this:

> ROLE1 -> /ui/ui1
>
> ROLE1 -> /ui/ui2
>
> ROLE2 -> /ui/ui2

How can I change **ROLE2 -> /ui/ui1** in Runtime?

Because, I storage in database. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PermissionEvaluator` that which will check authorization with custom your implementation, in which you can check database and compare roles in runtime.

More about how to use it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-permission-evaluator

If you don't want to use annotations on methods, here is how you can add custom method to Web Security Expressions [spring security:intercept-url pattern access="#id == 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185070/spring-securityintercept-url-pattern-access-id-1/14199105#14199105) . Then you should be able to use it in configuration like:

```
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/url1").access("hasPermission(#user,...)");
```

Other solution is to make use of custom filter in security filter chain that will check Authentication, url and database.